# Azure application gateway -unknown error. Please try again

Tags: azure, adfs

I am trying to set up ADFS Proxy servers behind an Azure Application Gateway but keep getting unknown error. Please try again when testing backend health.

I have 2 VMS in the backend pool with Windows 2012 Datacenter. I have set up the probes as follows :

Host: 127.0.0.1
Protocol : HTTPS
Path : /
Interval : 30 
Timeout : 30
Unhealthy Threshold : 3

NSGs on the Backend VMs have been opened to allow all traffic for testing but still get the error

Answer (score 0):

1. Since you say your NSGs allow traffic, check to ensure that your Firewalls on the VM itself are not blocking anything. In the Firewall settings check the boxes next to "enable file and printer sharing."
2. This seems obvious, but double-check that your VMs are all turned on and can ping each other. Also ensure that they are all joined to the domain.
3. Try removing the NSG temporarily to see if it works without it.
4. Allow the ports 65503-65534 in your NSGs and then check the status. These are necessary to be allowed to ensure that the App Gateway monitoring API can reach the endpoint for checking the health status.
5. Refer to this troubleshooting guide. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/application-gateway-troubleshooting-502
6. Check the Azure status to make sure there is not an outage. We recently had some outages in the Central South region. https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/status/